# How to migrate a Sharepoint Task List where all details are preserved?

Tags: wss-3.0, list

How to migrate a Sharepoint list to another list while preserving all the details?

I use WSS 3.0.

Comment: do you want to achieve this programmatically? or manually?

Comment: Exact duplicate - http://www.sharepointoverflow.com/questions/10011/which-is-the-easiest-way-to-migrate-entire-list-to-a-new-new-site/10754#10754

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One manual way to do this is to ensure your new list has the columns in the same order as your old list, then use the Datasheet view of both lists to copy/paste the data across.

Of course, this may be unmanagable if your list has more than few hundred items.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the size of your list, you can always save the list as a template and include all content.

List Tools > List > List Settings

Under **Permissions and Management** select **Save list as template**.

Give it appropriate names and descriptions and make sure to select **Include Content**.

Then just go to the subsite and add the list template there, in the same way that you'd add a new list or library.

Answer (score -1):

You can definitely migrate your entire lists and site collections preserving all meta data and versioning as well . Your security will be migrated without any loss as well.

Xavor SharePoint 2010 Migrator can easily restructure your contents on the same server. Just select the same server in both source and destination and then drag your documents from source side to a desired position on destination side and click migration. You can later delete your documents after migration and verification. It’s pretty simpler and straight forward. Please try an evaluation copy from here>>http://www.xavor.com/index.php/what-we-do/solutions/xavor-sharepoint-2010-migrator/download-free-xavor-sharepoint-2010-migrator-trial/